# VHDL: receive module randomly fails when counting bits

Tags: fpga, vhdl, protocol

**Background**

This is a personal project; it regards connecting an FPGA to a N64, the byte values that the FPGA receives are then sent through UART to my computer. It actually functions pretty well! At random times unfortunately, the device will fail, then recover. Through debugging, I've managed to find the problem, however I am stumped at how to fix it because I'm fairly incompetent with VHDL.

I've been toying with the VHDL for a couple days now and I may be incapable of resolving this.

**The Problem**

I have an oscilloscope measuring the N64 signal into the FPGA, and the other channel connects to the output of the FPGA. I also have digital pins recording the counter value.

Essentially, the N64 sends 9 data bits, including a STOP bit. The counter counts the data bits received and when I reach 9 bits, the FPGA starts transmitting via UART.

Here's correct behavior:
[image]

The FPGA is the blue waveform and the orange waveform is the input of the N64. For the duration of receiving, my FPGA "echos" the signal of the input for debugging purposes. After the FPGA counts to 9, it begins transmitting the data through UART. Notice that the digital pins count to 9 and the FPGA output goes LOW immediately after the N64 is finished.

Here's an example of a failure:

[image]

Notice that the counter skips bits 2 and 7! The FPGA reaches the end, waiting for the next start bit from the N64 but nothing. So the FPGA times out and recovers.

This is the VHDL for the N64 receive module. It contains the counter: s_bitCount.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;   
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity N64RX is
     port(
         N64RXD : in STD_LOGIC;                    --Data input
         clk25 : in STD_LOGIC;
         clr : in STD_LOGIC; 
         tdre : in STD_LOGIC;                      --detects when UART is ready
         transmit : out STD_LOGIC;                 --Signal to UART to transmit  
         sel : out STD_LOGIC; 
         echoSig : out STD_LOGIC;
         bitcount : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         data : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)   --The significant nibble
         );
end N64RX;

--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture N64RX of N64RX is 

type state_type is (start, delay2us, sigSample, waitForStop, waitForStart, timeout, count9bits, sendToUART);

signal state: state_type;
signal s_sel, s_echoSig, s_timeoutDetect : STD_LOGIC;
signal s_baudCount : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);  --Counting variable for baud rate in delay
signal s_bitCount : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);  --Counting variable for number of bits recieved 
signal s_data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);   --Signal for data

constant delay : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0) := "0110010";  --Provided 25MHz, 50 cycles is 2us 
constant delayLong : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0) := "1100100";

begin 

n64RX: process(clk25, N64RXD, clr, tdre)
begin
    if clr = '1' then
        s_timeoutDetect <= '0';
        s_echoSig <= '1';
        s_sel <= '0';
        state <= start;
        s_data <= "000000000";
        transmit <= '0'; 
        s_bitCount <= "0000";
        s_baudCount <= "0000000";  
    elsif (clk25'event and clk25 = '1') then    --on rising edge of clock input
        case state is
            when start =>   
                --s_timeoutDetect <= '0';
                s_sel <= '0';
                transmit <= '0';        --Don't request UART to transfer   
                s_data <= "000000000";
                s_bitCount <= X"0";   
                if N64RXD = '1' then
                    state <= start;
                elsif N64RXD = '0' then     --if Start bit detected
                    state <= delay2us;
                end if;    

            when delay2us =>                 --wait two microseconds to sample
                --s_timeoutDetect <= '0';
                s_sel <= '1';
                s_echoSig <= '0';
                if s_baudCount >= delay then    
                    state <= sigSample;
                else
                    s_baudCount <= s_baudCount + 1;
                    state <= delay2us;
                end if;  

            when sigSample => 
                --s_timeoutDetect <= '1';
                s_echoSig <= N64RXD;
                s_bitCount <= s_bitCount + 1;
                s_baudcount <= "0000000";
                s_data <= s_data(7 downto 0) & N64RXD;      
                state <= waitForStop;   

            when waitForStop => 
                s_echoSig <= N64RXD;
                if N64RXD = '0' then
                    state <= waitForStop;
                elsif N64RXD = '1' then
                    state <= waitForStart;
                end if;   

            when waitForStart => 
                s_echoSig <= '1';
                s_baudCount <= s_baudCount + 1; 
                if N64RXD = '0' then 
                    s_baudCount <= "0000000";
                    state <= delay2us;
                elsif N64RXD = '1' then 
                    if s_baudCount >= delayLong then
                        state <= timeout;
                    elsif s_bitCount >= X"9" then
                        state <= count9bits;
                    else
                        state <= waitForStart;
                    end if;
                end if;     

            when count9bits =>  
                s_sel <= '0';
                if tdre = '0' then
                    state <= count9bits;
                elsif tdre = '1' then
                    state <= sendToUART;
                end if;   

            when sendToUART =>
                transmit <= '1';
                if tdre = '0' then
                    state <= start;
                else
                    state <= sendToUART;
                end if;

            when timeout =>
                --s_timeoutDetect <= '1';
                state <= start;

        end case;   
    end if;
end process n64RX;  
--timeoutDetect <= s_timeoutDetect;
bitcount <= s_bitCount;
echoSig <= s_echoSig;
sel <= s_sel;
data <= s_data(4 downto 1);

end N64RX;
```

So, any ideas? Debugging tips? Tips on coding Finite State Machines?

In the meantime, I'll keep playing around with it (I'll have it eventually)! Help me Stack Exchange, you're my only hope!

**Edit**

A further discovery in my debugging, the states will jump from waitForStart back to waitForStop. I gave each state a value with waitForStart equal to '5' and waitForStop equal to '4'. See the image below:
[image]

Comment: In your first case block, there is the line "s_bitCount <= X"0";" Is that X a typo?

Comment: @trav1s No, that "X" denotes hexadecimal. So X"0" is actually "0000" in binary.

Comment: Okay, I am more of a Verilog person. Not particularly related to solving the problem, but I am curious what you are doing with the N64? Reading the ROM? Building an emulator?

Comment: @trav1s I understand, I was taught VHDL so I stick with it. I'm building a BT N64 controller, with the FPGA as the dongle side (I didn't want to bit bang with a MCU). The BT modules I'm looking at use UART, which is why I'm using that protocol.

Comment: If possible could you show what you have above, but including all I/O and internal registers? The number of signals isn't too high and will really help trace the error.

Comment: @trav1s It's not much, just a UART TX module and some other very tiny modules. As for I/O, it's just a couple pins for input and UART output. I already isolated the cause to the N64RX component.

Comment: I see. There seems to be more than one signal which could cause this error if their control logic is faulty. We know s_bitCount has a problem, but we don't know where in the control logic it is going wrong. Prime suspect may be the state register, but If we could trace the code while having observability of all signals, the problem would be apparent.

Comment: Observing all signals over the scope might be impossible, so you may need to build a test in simulation which reproduces the error.

Comment: @trav1s I can try simulating it a few times, however I haven't seen the issue produced there. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks for the insight so far!

Comment: I got a couple errors running the code through a linter. Signals N64RXD and tdre should not be used in the sensitivity list of the sequential process, line 36.

Comment: Can you get the clock to show up on the display? I didn't have time to read your code, but looking at how slow the LSB reacts, I am thinking you are undersampling. I saw a 25MHz clock line - that means the [fastest signal you can sample is 12.5Mbps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

Comment: @trav1s - Sensitivity lists are bogus in synthesis. ;)

Comment: @trav1s Thanks for the pointer, I removed those parameters; you're right, those aren't necessary. I still have the issue unfortunately. With the scope, I added signals to detect which state I'm in. For some reason, the FPGA jumps from the "waitForStart" back to the "waitForStop" with no state in between! This is why it's not counting because the FPGA does not reach the state where it counts the bit. The "jump back" appears to be the issue.

Comment: Throw tdre up on your waveform display and see what it's doing.  Ask yourself what can interfere with output.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Hello Aaron, the N64 bit length is 1us vs the 25MHz clock. I can up the sampling to 50MHz, but I believe their is any issue with my state machine, I put some details in my previous comment.

Comment: But "waitForStart" -> "waitForStop" transition is invalid. There's no way to make that jump in a single cycle. Check very closely to make sure there is not a very brief state in between. Otherwise, there must be a hardware/timing fault.

Comment: @DavidKoontz The tdre is an input from the UART TX to tell my N64RX when it's ready for another transmission. I got that UART cranking at 115200 so it's got plenty of head room. The N64 doesn't make another signal for 1.6ms and I'm only sending one byte.

Comment: @trav1s I was just as surprised, I don't see a transition occurring between the two so I'm a little stumped how this happened.

Comment: @NickWilliams Yes, but where does tdre come from?  is it impulse filtered or otherwise derived from the clock operating your state machine?  If it's not filtered you could be suffering from noise to fast to see with your scope.  Imagine a hardware issue as a possibility in addition to a problem with design.

Comment: @DavidKoontz, if tdre was removed from the sensitivity list then you are chasing a red herring. That signal simply isn't relevant in the faulty state transition.

Comment: @NickWilliams, what other information do you have about the failure? Can you reproduce it every time, or does it happen randomly and unpredictably?

Comment: @trav1s The "jump back" for the states occurs everytime I see the issue. I posted a screenshot in my answer so you know I'm not crazy! Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @travis Signal Integrity.  Nothing to do with sensitivity lists.  Think setup time problems for state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see a synchronizer on the rx data line.

All asynchronous inputs must be synchronized to the sampling clock. There are a couple of reasons for this: metastability and routing. These are different problems but are inter-related.

It takes time for signals to propagate through the FPGA fabric. The clock network inside the FPGA is designed to compensate for these "travel" delays so that all flip flops within the FPGA see the clock at the exact same moment. The normal routing network does not have this, and instead relies on the rule that all signals must be stable for a little bit of time before the clock changes and remain stable for a little bit of time after the clock changes. These little bits of time are known as the setup and hold times for a given flip flop. The place and route component of the toolchain has a very good understanding of the routing delays for the specific device and makes a basic assumption that a signal does not violate the setup and hold times of the flip flops in the FPGA. With that assumption and knowledge (and a timing constraints file) it can properly place the logic within the FPGA and ensure that all the logic that looks at a given signal sees the same value at every clock tick.

When you have signals that are not synchronized to the sampling clock you can end up in the situation where one flip flop sees the "old" value of a signal since the new value has not had time to propagate over. Now you're in the undesirable situation where logic looking at the same signal sees two different values. This can cause wrong operation, crashed state machines and all kinds of hard to diagnose havoc.

The other reason why you must synchronize all your input signals is something called metastability. There are volumes written on this subject but in a nutshell, digital logic circuitry is at its most basic level an analog circuit. When your clock line rises the state of the input line is captured and if that input is not a stable high or low level at that time, an unknown "in-between" value can be captured by the sampling flip flop.

As you know, FPGAs are digital beasts and do not react well to a signal that is neither high nor low. Worse, if that indeterminate value makes its way past the sampling flip flop and into the FPGA it can cause all kinds of weirdness as larger portions of the logic now see an indeterminate value and try to make sense of it.

The solution is to synchronize the signal. At its most basic level this means you use a chain of flip flops to capture the input. Any metastable level that might have been captured by the first flip flop and managed to make it out gets another chance to be resolved before it hits your complex logic. Two flip flops are usually more than sufficient to synchronize inputs.

A basic synchronizer looks like this:

```
entity sync_2ff is
port (
    async_in : in std_logic;
    clk : in std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    sync_out : out std_logic
);
end;

architecture a of sync_2ff is
begin

signal ff1, ff2: std_logic;

-- It's nice to let the synthesizer know what you're doing. Altera's way of doing it as follows:
ATTRIBUTE altera_attribute : string;
ATTRIBUTE altera_attribute OF ff1 : signal is "-name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION ""FORCED IF ASYNCHRONOUS""";
ATTRIBUTE altera_attribute OF a : architecture is "-name SDC_STATEMENT ""set_false_path -to *|sync_2ff:*|ff1 """;

-- also set the 'preserve' attribute to ff1 and ff2 so the synthesis tool doesn't optimize them away
ATTRIBUTE preserve: boolean;
ATTRIBUTE preserve OF ff1: signal IS true;
ATTRIBUTE preserve OF ff2: signal IS true;

synchronizer: process(clk, rst)
begin
if rst = '1' then
    ff1 <= '0';
    ff2 <= '0';
else if rising_edge(clk) then
    ff1 <= async_in;
    ff2 <= ff1;
    sync_out <= ff2;
end if;
end process synchronizer;
end sync_2ff;
```

Connect the physical pin for the N64 controller's rx data line to the async_in input of the synchronizer, and connect the sync_out signal to your UART's rxd input.

Unsynchronized signals can cause *weird* issues. Make sure any input connected to an FPGA element that isn't synchronized to the clock of the process reading the signal is synchronized. This includes pushbuttons, UART 'rx' and 'cts' signals... anything that is not synchronized to the clock that the FPGA is using to sample the signal.

(An aside: I wrote the page at [www.mixdown.ca/n64dev](http://mixdown.ca/n64dev) many years ago. I just realized that I broke the link when I last updated the site and will fix it in the morning when I'm back at a computer. I had no idea so many people used that page!)

Comment: Thanks for the great and comprehensive answer! I'm going to give this a try and make my machine more robust.

Comment: It actually has very little to do with metastability (although that's a concern, too), and everything to do with the differing path delays from the asynchronous input to the various FFs that hold the bits of the state variable.

Comment: You're right, @DaveTweed; I tend to lump the two together and that is wrong-headed thinking.

Comment: I've edited my answer to take @DaveTweed's comments into account.

Comment: @akohlsmith Amazing! I added the synchronizer and it was the solution. Also, that's an incredible coincidence that you wrote the mixdown page; I found a bunch of resources on the N64 protocol that referrenced that article and I was disappointed the link was broken. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that you are using unsynchronized signals to make decisions in your state machine. You should be feeding all of those external signals through double-FF synchronizers before using them in the state machine.

It's a subtle problem with state machines that can arise in any state transition that involves a change to two or more bits in the state variable. If you use an unsynchronized input, one of the bits might change while the other one fails to change. This takes you to a different state from the one intended, and it might or might not be a legal state.

That last statement is why you should also always have a default case (in VHDL, `when others => ...`) in your state machine case statement that takes you from any illegal state to a legal one.

Comment: Yeah, this was the conclusion I was about to isolate, but I didn't want to jump to it before getting enough information...

Comment: I used to think that `when others =>` was helping, but it turns out it doesn't get you what you claim (under any synthesiser I have used) *unless* you add attributes to ensure that the synth understands you want a "safe" state machine.  The normal behaviour is to optimise to a one-hot representation and not provide recovery logic. See http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/40093.html and http://www.synopsys.com/Company/Publications/SynopsysInsight/Pages/Art5-fpga-designs-IssQ1-13.aspx for example.

Comment: Wow! That's a great tip and it worked like a charm.