# VHDL: Counter occasionally does not reset

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm using ISE Project Navigator 14.7 with a Xilinx XC95144XL-5TQ100C CPLD in conjunction with a LM1881 video sync separator.  I've also got a 14.3 MHz clock.  I'm trying to generate VSYNC pulses in response to the LM1881 FIELD line changing (and yes, I know the LM1881 also has a VSYNC output; but I'm constrained due to the PCB I'm using which only allows me to view FIELD).

Here is the code I am using to generate the VSYNC signal (I tried to remove non-relevant parts):

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity outputGenFromLm1881 is

    Port ( clock14_3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              lm1881Field : in  STD_LOGIC;
              vsync2_prime : out  STD_LOGIC);

end outputGenFromLm1881;

architecture Behavioral of outputGenFromLm1881 is

    constant cyclesPerVsync : natural := 238875;
    constant cyclesPerHalfLine : natural := 455;
    constant cyclesPerLine : natural := cyclesPerHalfLine*2;
    constant cyclesPerVsync2Pulse : natural := ((cyclesPerLine * 11)/2);

    -- we need 18 bits for range of vsync plus an extra bit to detect/prevent wrapping back to 0

    signal iVsync2Count : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal fieldOld : std_logic := '0';

begin

vsync2_prime <= '0' when (unsigned(iVsync2Count) < cyclesPerVsync2Pulse) else '1';

lm1881FieldThink: process(clock14_3)

begin

    if (rising_edge(clock14_3)) then

        -- if field has changed
        if (lm1881Field /= fieldOld) then           

            iVsync2Count <= (others => '0');
            fieldOld <= not fieldOld;

        -- we never want to wraparound back to 0 unintentionally
        elsif (iVsync2Count(18) = '0') then

            iVsync2Count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(iVsync2Count) + 1);           

        end if;

    end if;

end process lm1881FieldThink;
```

Most of the time it behaves correctly as shown here:
[image: Text]

But occasionally, the counter never resets even though fieldOld is getting changed properly.

[image: Text]

There's nothing else that modifies iVsync2Count except this process so I'm thinking somehow the section of the process that increments iVsync2Count is taking precedence over the reset.  The trouble is I can't see *how* this is possible or how to fix it.

Can anyone explain why iVsync2Count sometimes does not get properly reset?

Comment: The diagrams are not from a simulation, but traced from real hardware? Have you synchronized lm1881Field to clock14_3?

Comment: Yes, this is real hardware.  I thought that what I was doing in my process was good enough to synchronize but apparently this is where I'm going wrong.  I'm not sure how to synchronize lm1881Field to clock14_3 (but I've taken a stab at it in my response to Dave Tweed).

Comment: @MattOwnby Can you ask a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `lm1881Field` as an input to your state machine. I'm guessing that this input is not synchronized to your 14.3 MHz clock.

In the state machine, this input affects 20 different state bits — 19 in your counter `iVsync2Count`, plus `fieldOld`. Each of those bits has logic associated with it that determines that bit's next state. Each of those pieces of logic has a different delay (from the asynchronous input) associated with it.

So, if that input changes state at a "random" time with respect to the clock, there's a chance that some of the bits will see the change, and some will not. This leaves you in an inconsistent state.

This is why **all** inputs to state machines **must** be properly synchronized to the state machine clock.

Comment: So does that mean I would add a flip-flop that is triggered by the clock and the D input would be the random lm1881 field?  or is there a cleaner way to accomplish that.  (Thanks for the reply!!!)

Comment: UPDATE: Found this thread that explains it in detail: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79821/vhdl-receive-module-randomly-fails-when-counting-bits/79830#79830 (I'm sure Dave Tweed is getting tired of answering the same question but I'm very grateful!)